# validation annotation constraint not working

Tags: java, spring, validation

I wrote a test, that should test the validations of my class CasinoDto, but they are not working, the assertion fails.
The import should be correct, maybe i wrote a wrong test but i dont know where the error is.

CasinoDto class:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
public class CasinoDto {

    @Id
    private Long casinoId;

    @Size(min = 10, max=100000)
    private Float sales;

    private String country;
    private String place;

    @NotNull
    private String street;
    @NotNull
    private String houseNumber;
}
```

The test which is not working:

```
 private CasinoDto casinoDto;
    private static Validator validator;
    private static ValidatorFactory validatorFactory;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void createValidator(){
        validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void setCasinoDto(){
        casinoDto = CasinoDto.builder()
                        .casinoId(1L)
                        .country("yes")
                        .houseNumber("12")
                        .place("mareo")
                        .sales(20000f)
                        .street("irgendwo")
                        .build();
    }

    @AfterEach
    void testViolation(){
        Set<ConstraintViolation<CasinoDto>> violations = validator.validate(casinoDto);
        Assertions.assertFalse(violations.isEmpty());
    }

    @Test
    void testNotNull(){
        casinoDto.setStreet(null);
    }
```

I already checked the dependencies and they should be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with the field `sales` - you cannot use `@Size` with number types. According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Size.html):

> Supported types are:
>
> CharSequence (length of character sequence is evaluated)
>
> Collection (collection size is evaluated)
>
> Map (map size is evaluated)
>
> Array (array length is evaluated)

In your case (with Float) you need to use a different set of annotations:

```
    @NotNull
    @DecimalMax("100000")
    @DecimalMin("10")
    private Float sales;
```

Notice that I also placed `@NotNull` because `@DecimalMin` and `@DecimalMax` consider nullable elements as valid (it's the common approach of Bean Validation API).

All annotations are from the package `javax.validation.constraints`.